# RegExp for PostalCode dart

Tags: dart

I'm trying to find the code to check the zip code format. This is the code I have:

```
validator: ((codigopostal) {
                    if (codigopostal == null || codigopostal.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Por favor, insira o seu Codigo Postal';
                    } else if (RegExp(r"^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\- ]{0,10}[a-z0-9]$")
                        .hasMatch(_codigopostal.text)) {
                      return 'Por favor, insira um Codigo Postal no formato correto';
                    }
                    return null;
                  }),
```

and this is what I found about my country "Portugal" :

```
<postCodeRegex territoryId="PT" >\d{4}([\-]\d{3})?</postCodeRegex>
```

I'm not able to adjust to my code, I also don't know if what I searched is right

Desired format(NNNN-NNN)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by you can't adjust your code, but the regex for NNNN-NNN is `\d{4}-\d{3}`. The regex you already found will match with or without the trailing hyphen and 3 digits

Comment: So I replace this one       RegExp(r"\d{4}-\d{3}")   with this one?     RegExp(r"^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\- ]{0,10}[a-z0-9]$"  and I have the format (NNNN-NNN)?

Comment: I said "I can't adjust it to my code" because I don't know if this is correct: RegExp(r"\d{4}-\d{3}") , if it has the "r" or not, or if there is a character missing

Comment: Ah, I see - If what you need is to tell the user when the code is invalid, then what you'll want in your code is this: `... } else if (!RegExp(r"\d{4}-\d{3}").hasMatch(codigopostal)) { ...`. Notice the `!` at the beginning of the conditional. That means it will only return the validation error if the regex for the correct formatting does *not* match.

Comment: That will make the last 3 digits always required - If the last three should be optional, then use the regex you found above: RegExp(r"\d{4}([\-]\d{3})?").

By the way, when a string literal is prefixed with 'r', like so: `r"hello"` that means it's a raw string. In a raw string, every character is interpreted literally, including backslashes; so there are no escaped characters in a raw string. It's ideal for writing regex expressions, since they often contain many backslashes

Comment: ok thanks a lot for the help and explanation. Now it's checking

Comment: The code is country-dependent, if it exists at all! What are you accomplishing by trying to "validate" it?

Comment: it is NNNN-NNN. (N - number)